# How to fix "Avoid passing null as the view root" in android?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

In my android app, I create a dialog like this:

```
private void handleEdit() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_gallery, null);

    final AlertDialog d = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setView(dialoglayout)
    .setTitle(R.string.edit)
    .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, null)
    .create();

    CheckBox mainCB = (CheckBox)dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.main);
    CheckBox usedCB = (CheckBox)dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.used);
    mainCB.setChecked(image.getIsMain());
    usedCB.setChecked(image.getApproved());

    mainCB.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if (Network.isNetworkAvailable(GalleryScreen.this)) {
                new Async_update_image_state(GalleryScreen.this, fish, image, !image.getIsMain(), image.getApproved(), false);
                d.dismiss();
            } else {
                Popup.ShowErrorMessage(GalleryScreen.this, R.string.no_internet, false);
            }
        }
    });

    usedCB.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if (Network.isNetworkAvailable(GalleryScreen.this)) {
                new Async_update_image_state(GalleryScreen.this, fish, image, false, !image.getApproved(), true);
                d.dismiss();
            } else {
                Popup.ShowErrorMessage(GalleryScreen.this, R.string.no_internet, false);
            }
        }
    });

    d.show();
}
```

But I get a warning on `View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_gallery, null);` underlining the `null`.

```
Avoid passing null as the view root (needed to resolve layout parameters on the inflated layout's root element)
```

What does this mean and how can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24832497/avoid-passing-null-as-the-view-root-need-to-resolve-layout-parameters-on-the-in

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26404951/avoid-passing-null-as-the-view-root-warning-when-inflating-view-for-use-by-ale

Comment: In this case it's OK to pass null. Add a `@SuppressLint` annotation so it's not bugging you.

Answer (score 14):

this works for me

```
View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.dialog, null);
```

without any warnings nor errors.

Comment: this is the correct answer according to http://stackoverflow.com/a/26596164/1708390

Answer (score 8):

When inflating a layout for use in a dialog, You can safely pass null here and ignore the warning.

From [This Link](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/05/layout-inflation-as-intended/)

> The issue here is that AlertDialog.Builder supports a custom view, but
>   does not provide an implementation of setView() that takes a layout
>   resource; so you must inflate the XML manually. However, because the
>   result will go into the dialog, which does not expose its root view
>   (in fact, it doesn’t exist yet), we do not have access to the eventual
>   parent of the layout, so we cannot use it for inflation. It turns out,
>   this is irrelevant, because AlertDialog will erase any LayoutParams on
>   the layout anyway and replace them with match_parent.

Comment: I'd like to use @SuppressWarnings for this but don't know what to use; any ideas?

- edit - 
Found it, @SuppressWarnigns("InflateParams")

Answer (score 2):

Instead of :

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_gallery, null);
```

do:

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_gallery, parent, false);
```

Using a `@SuppressLint annotation` as suggested by `Eugen` in the comment above might "suppress" the warning, but it doesn't solve the problem.Using null as an argument for the ViewGroup will cause you problems in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_gallery, null);
```

try

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_gallery, null, false);
```

It will not attach view to the parent that is null in your case.

See details on [Android Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate(int,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean))

Comment: This is meaningless, because if you look the Android's source code you'll see this implementation: `public View inflate(int resource, ViewGroup root) {
        return inflate(resource, root, root != null);
    }`. I mean, sooner or later it will do the same effect exactly.