# No parent found for "avoid passing null as the view root"

Tags: java, android, layout-inflater

I have this code, where I define my own `AlertDialog.Builder`:

```
public class UnlockDialog extends AlertDialog.Builder {
    public UnlockDialog(Activity context) {
        super(context);

        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View dlgView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.unlock_dialog, null); 
        setView(dlgView);
    }
}
```

the code works fine, but I get a warning on the `inflater.inflate` call:

> Avoid passing null as the view root (needed to resolve layout parameters on the inflated layout's root element)

I had this issue as well in my adapters, where I could resolve it using providing a `parent` and `false`, as I found here: [Avoid passing null as the view root (need to resolve layout parameters on the inflated layout's root element)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24832497/avoid-passing-null-as-the-view-root-need-to-resolve-layout-parameters-on-the-in)

However, in the case above, I don't seem to have a `parent` available. I tried `context.getParent()`, but that didn't work.

Comment: alertdialog builder is not really meant to be extended, imho

Comment: @njzk2 Possibly, but is that relevant to the question? `setView()` is still a public method in vanilla `AlertDialog.Builder`.

Comment: agreed, that was just a general comment.

Comment: @njzk2 thanks for that remark. I'll also look into doing it the "right" way. Any tips?

Comment: `Builder`s follow, as the name suggest, the `Builder` pattern. The basic principle here is that all the calls can be chained, resulting in a compact and not so bulky code. Typically, if this builder is going to be user in several places, you could put it in a static helper method. Extending a class is more usually used for overriding behaviors, or mutualizing common behaviors. (in your case, it could make sense if a/ a lot of alerts are using the same view and b/ there is a little more to mutualize than just the content view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning should not apply in this case. The `root` parameter, when `attachToRoot` is false, is only used to call its `generateDefaultLayoutParams()` method and assign the resulting `LayoutParams` to the inflated view.

In this case, the dialog will overwrite them, so they would be unused anyway.

Please check [this article](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/05/layout-inflation-as-intended/), particularly the section *Every Rule Has An Exception*.

> However, because the result will go into the dialog, which does not
>   expose its root view (in fact, it doesn’t exist yet), we do not have
>   access to the eventual parent of the layout, so we cannot use it for
>   inflation. It turns out, this is irrelevant, because AlertDialog will
>   erase any LayoutParams on the layout anyway and replace them with
>   match_parent.

Comment: Ok, that's clear. So fixing the warning is simply done by repressing it?

Comment: @BartFriederichs Yes.