# match_parent not working xml android

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to make buttons wich would change part of the context, but the match_parent not working propertly.

got java main file:

```
class public MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        Button bn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.navbar_1);
        Button bn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.navbar_2);

        bn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentMeters fr = new FragmentMeters();
                FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.layout_to_replace, fr);
                ft.commit();

            }
        });

        bn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentValues fr = new FragmentValues();
                FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.layout_to_replace, fr);
                ft.commit();



            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Then another java class FragmentMeters (and similar FragmentValues):

```
public class FragmentMeters extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_meters, null);

        return view;
    }

}
```

And main XML, something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/navbar"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="82dp"
    android:background="@color/highlighted_text_material_dark"
    android:weightSum="4">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/navbar_1"
        android:text="@string/navbar_1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/navbar_2"
        android:text="@string/navbar_2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_to_replace"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/navbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/dim_foreground_disabled_material_dark"
    android:layout_height="82dp"
    android:weightSum="4"/>
```

And I'm trying to replace the LinearLayout (id="layout_to_replace") with this fragment_meters.xml:

```
 <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/navbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="82dp"
        android:background="@color/dim_foreground_disabled_material_dark"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="METERS"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

But I'm getting this:

[image]

Instead of matching it parent's width/height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i know this issue,in some cases when inflating a layout the arguments layout_width and layout_height change to wrap content.

i suggest to you to set layout params manually after inflating:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_meters, null);
view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

(for height put what u want)

Comment: Yes, this works fine for me. Thanks ! But I had to use RadioGroup.LayoutParams instead of LayoutParams only

Comment: But how can I set it others than match_parent or match_content? :/

Comment: your talking about height?

Comment: y height or width, but specific, not parent or content ?

Comment: i will post a new answer

Answer (score 0):

Deleting `android:weightSum="4"` from the `LinearLayout` with the id  `@+id/layout_to_replace` should solve your problem.

You should also consider adding the `gravity` attribute on the corresponding `TextView`.

Answer (score 0):

the best way to it is add resource file in values folder that called dimens.xml, and add there a dimen, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <dimen name="width">100dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height">100dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

and in the java code you should get those values from resources by context, like this:

```
int width = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.width);
int height = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.height);
```

Comment: Thanks, just had to use getAction(). instead of getApplicationContext(). because of using it inside of Fragment. Wich is returning the float. Thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

@tomáš-john, the issue is exactly like @liran-peretz assumed: your view from `fragment_meters` does not have `"match_parent"` in runtime. But the solution should be different.

The reason for this is because you passing `null` as "view root" when you inflate this view in the `FragmentMeters`! When no "view root" is passed at inflation - then layout params of "root element" from `fragment_meters` xml is ignored and thus this is not `"match_parent"` in `LinearLayout`.

Instead you have to do:

`inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_meters, parent)`

or with `attachToRoot` set to `false` *(when you don't want your view to be added to the parent)*.

`inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_meters, parent, false);`

Some more links from the following answer could be helpful as well:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25528527/3134602