# Accessing SharedPreferences from Dialog CheckBox

Tags: java, android

I am trying to load some SharedPreferences data (checkbox state) from a dialog. I have the following code:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.proficiency_dialog, null);
        getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        updateProficiency = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.update_proficiency);
        updateProficiency.setOnClickListener(this);
        cancelProficiency = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.cancel_proficiency);
        cancelProficiency.setOnClickListener(this);
        STR_Prof_checkbox = (CheckBox) getDialog().findViewById(R.id.STR_save_checkbox);
        loadSavedPreferences();
        setCancelable(false);
        return view;
    }

    public void loadSavedPreferences() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
        boolean STRProfCheckBoxValue = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("STR_Save_CheckBox_Value", false);
        if (STRProfCheckBoxValue) {
            STR_Prof_checkbox.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            STR_Prof_checkbox.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
```

However, I receive a null pointer exception on the `loadSavedPreferences()` method. What am I missing that's causing the error?

LOGCAT:

```
01-18 01:51:55.273 26730-26730/com.oozhangem.dd5echaracter E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.oozhangem.dd5echaracter, PID: 26730
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.CheckBox.setChecked(boolean)' on a null object reference
     at com.oozhangem.dd5echaracter.ProficiencyDialog.loadSavedPreferences(ProficiencyDialog.java:47)
     at com.oozhangem.dd5echaracter.ProficiencyDialog.onCreateView(ProficiencyDialog.java:35)
     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5294)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

Comment: Please post your logcat error output.

Comment: Yes, logcat will be usefull.
But i think getContext() is null. You can get Context from container.

And off top: don't use inflater with null. Use conteiner object as parameter.

Comment: Added logcat, @Puzirki and could you explain using container objects as parameters?

Comment: He is saying make `loadSharedPreferences` accept a Context parameter, and call it with `loadSharedPreferences(container.getContext());` That shouldn't fix this issue, but it's a good practice regardless.

Comment: Michael Zhang, Take a look this thread about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24832497/avoid-passing-null-as-the-view-root-need-to-resolve-layout-parameters-on-the-in

And:
https://possiblemobile.com/2013/05/layout-inflation-as-intended/

Comment: Thanks, will give it a read.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
```

With

```
SharedPreferences preferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Or

```
SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getPreferences(0);
```

Also replace reference of `STR_Prof_checkbox` with below.

```
STR_Prof_checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.STR_save_checkbox);
```

Comment: I have other activities which use  
`SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());`
So I would imagine that this is not the issue?

Comment: `onCreateView` is a method of `fragment` not of `Activity`.

Comment: My mistake - i meant fragment. I am using fragments for swipe views.

Comment: `getContext()` returns `activity context` not `fragment context`