# How to getText from another Layout from editText Android

Tags: android

I am making an activity in which an alertDialog will appear. The dialog will have a view which contains:
Linear layout with two editText (Numeric texts) and then setHeight(wrapContent). You can see below.

[image]

Hope you are understanding now what i am doing. Here the view is a xml file which i created and it is not the activity's xml file. Now I want that when a user put the pin in the editText then i can get it and confirm it or whatever i want. But the problem is that i am not getting anything when i call getText(). Here is my code.

```
LayoutInflater factory = getLayoutInflater();
        View view = factory.inflate(R.layout.zalert_pass_enable, null); // zalert_pass.. is the xml file

        EditText passInput1 = view.findViewById(R.id.inputPass);
        EditText passInput2 = view.findViewById(R.id.inputPassConfirm);

       String value = passInput1.getText().toString().trim();
```

I edited my code to so that you can understand, this is not the actual code but it can easily tell my problem. When i toast the value String then i get nothing. Like there are 0 charaters. But i am putting 4 charaters at least each time. Now i know that the problem is in the process of linking the xml file to inflator.

```
 infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
```

See the above line of code. This a well upvoted [answer of stackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24832497/avoid-passing-null-as-the-view-root-need-to-resolve-layout-parameters-on-the-in). which tells us that we should not null the inflator. We should give it parent. But what will be the parent in my case.

[image]

You can see the picture and that is my problem and i want a solution for that, please help.

Comment: Add .toString(); with String value = passInput1.getText().toString();

Comment: no this is not the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line  `Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);`  after you are inflating view and use it to get `edittext` object like this

```
LayoutInflater factory = getLayoutInflater();
    View view = factory.inflate(R.layout.zalert_pass_enable, null); 
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context); // add this line
    EditText passInput1 = dialog.findViewById(R.id.inputPass);
    EditText passInput2 = dialog.findViewById(R.id.inputPassConfirm);

   String value = passInput1.getText().toString().trim();
```

Comment: this is not a problem, my problem is stated at the end of the question

Comment: Actually, your answer gave me a hint. It was not completely correct. Problem was I was putting getActivity() instead of getContext(). Second wrong part was alert.view(R.layout.xmlFile) and the correct one was alert.view(view). This is how it is working. thanks